# my mediaelement.js player does not load correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, mediaelement

I'm integrating the mediaelement.js player to my website. When I configure a play button to cause the the player to appear it does not load the entire player. I have to press the play button three times in order to load the player.

When I press the button an iframe opens:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-id="<?php echo $video['id']['videoId'];?>" data-title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $video['snippet']['title'] ); ?>" data-source="youtube" id="ic<?php echo $video['id']['videoId'];?>" class="btn-play"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> <?php echo $search_play_but; ?></button></a>
<div id="player-<?php echo $video['id']['videoId'];?>" class="player clearfix">
```

This is the iframe code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mediaelement/latest/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <script>$('audio').mediaelementplayer();</script>
    <?php
    require_once('../admin/config.php');
    require_once('../includes/url_slug.php'); 

    $json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$_GET["id"].'&key='.$youtube_key.'&part=snippet');
    $yt_data = json_decode($json);
    $yt_id = $_GET["id"];
    ?>

    //this is the iframe
    <div id="player-<?php echo $video['id']['videoId'];?>" class="player clearfix"></div>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mediaelement/latest/mediaelementplayer.css">

    <script>
        MediaElement('player1', {success: function(me) {    
        me.play();
        }});
    </script>
    <body>
        <audio preload="auto" id="player1" preload="none" controls>
            <source autoplay="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $yt_id; ?>" type="video/x-youtube">
        </audio>
<?php 
 $count++; 
?>
```

When it is only the player, it loads at once:

http://escuchala.com/includes/youtube.php?id=VRJmcxCrAOA

but in the searches you have to press the button three times to play to play:

http://escuchala.com/music/si-tu-no-estas-antonio-cartagena

Comment: In Chrome I see the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function" which seems to be caused by the matching js library not being loaded like it is in the single player page. I can't get the player to work at all because of that, never mind only after 3 clicks.

Comment: solve: escuchala.com/includes/youtube.php?id=VRJmcxCrAOA

Comment: At the end of the code of youtube.php I miss this: `    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mediaelement/latest/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <script>$('audio').mediaelementplayer();</script>
`

Comment: check again: http://escuchala.com/music/the-champion-feat-ludacris-carrie-underwood

Comment: Same problem although once I did get the player to start after 3 clicks, but more often it wouldn't appear correctly and the console error would still appear.

Comment: after the third click, it starts to work alone but only until it updates

Comment: how you can help me @steve

Answer (score 0):

thats what I refer:
at escuchala.com/includes/youtube.php?id=Htu3va7yDMg

The player is displayed once. ready to play the music.

check the images

[first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtRjr.jpg)

[second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8sIY.jpg)

[in the third click it works as it should.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6wZC.jpg)